# Map inside Map in input's path

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Is it possible to access inner map (value of outer map) in Spring's form:input tag, like this?

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, MyObject>> // my map structure

<form:input path="map[4].[13].foo" /> //shows error
```

foo is a field of MyObject class with created getters and setters.

Comment: Try with just `map[4][13].foo`

Comment: I tried, seems not to work anyway.

Comment: Is map a scoped variable?  If yes, then use ${ }

Comment: @rickz But how can I set variable when I use path attribute?

Comment: Where is map created?

Comment: In Java code and passed as modelAttribute.